# clearInterval() not working in an if/else statement with recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to build a countdown that switches between play time and work time. It starts with 10 seconds of work then when it reaches 0 seconds we clear the interval and set it to 'play' and call the function again...

```
var model = {
intervalID: 0,
status: 'work',
workSeconds: 10,
playSeconds: 10,
}

function startCountdown(){
if (model.status === 'work') {

    model.countdown = model.workSeconds;
    model.intervalID = setInterval(function(){

        model.countdown--;
        if (model.countdown > 0) {
            console.log('work', model.countdown);
        } else {
            model.status = 'play';
            clearInterval(model.indervalId);
            startCountdown();
        }
    }, 1000);
} else if (model.status === 'play') {

    model.countdown = model.playSeconds;
    model.intervalID = setInterval(function(){
        model.countdown--;
        if (model.countdown > 0) {
            console.log('play', model.countdown);
        } else {
            model.status = 'work';
            clearInterval(model.indervalId);
            startCountdown();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
}
startCountdown();
```

This function is supposed to console log a 10 second countdown for work, then when the countdown reaches 0 switch to a 10 seconds countdown of play, and keep doing that.

At the moment it looks like no intervals are being cleared and both intervals just keep setting each other in a feedback loop.

Why are the intervals not being cleared?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo. `clearInterval(model.indervalId);` should be `clearInterval(model.intervalID);`.

I'd use `setTimeout` for this too, but I guess you already know about that.

Comment: Sorry about that Oskar, what an oversight on my part. I did not think about setTimeout I will have a look. Thank you!